# Prevent CSS Grid content from overflowing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-grid

I am trying to center horizontally, using Css grid.

When grid container is smaller than contents, the contents overflows.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;

  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;

  background: rgb(234, 247, 179);
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

.mid {
  grid-column: 2;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.content {
  background: rgb(142, 225, 250);
  width: 250px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>
  content div overflows if container width is less than content width 
</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="mid">
    <div class="content">
      some content .........................
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Same demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-css-grid-children-overflow-5yp0i), but the container size can be changed easily (uses React)

How to make the container **constrain** the contents, when container size is smaller than the contents?

*There are other solutions, but i am trying to understand how Css grid works.*

Comment: `min-width: 0;` to the grid item